# ORA-01722 invalid number - table join

Tags: oracle, ora-01722

So i have this simple oracle query which returns me the expected record:

```
SELECT to_number(substr(nr_key,5,4)) as numero
FROM fattura_pa 
 LEFT JOIN fattura_pa_status on status_id = id
WHERE ute = 'BX' and length(nr_key) < 21
and to_number(substr(nr_key,5,4)) = 88
```

If I transform it into this:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT to_number(substr(nr_key,5,4)) as numero
  FROM fattura_pa 
    LEFT JOIN fattura_pa_status on status_id = id
  WHERE ute = 'BX' and length(nr_key) < 21
) 
where numero = 88
```

It gives me the "ORA-01722 invalid number" error

I cannot undrestand why, since my "numero = 88" is actually a number...

The strangest thing is that if I comment the join, the query runs again:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT to_number(substr(nr_key,5,4)) as numero
  FROM fattura_pa 
  --LEFT JOIN fattura_pa_status on status_id = id
  WHERE ute = 'BX' and length(nr_key) < 21
) 
where numero = 88
```

And the join has nothing to do with te "numero" field...

As asked, i post here the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "FE_ENGINE"."FATTURA_PA" 
   (    "UTE" VARCHAR2(2 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NR_KEY" VARCHAR2(21 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PROGRESSIVO_INVIO" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "XML_CREATO" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "XML_FILE_NAME" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "POSIZIONE" NUMBER(4,0) DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "D3_FILE_NAME" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SPEDITA_IL" DATE, 
    "ACCETTATA_IL" DATE, 
    "ARCHIVIATA_IL" DATE, 
    "STATUS_ID" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "RIELABORARE" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ROW_INSTIME" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ROW_UPTIME" DATE, 
    "NR_KEY_OLD" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "UQ_FATTURA_PA_FILE_NAME_POSIT" UNIQUE ("XML_FILE_NAME", "POSIZIONE")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "D3_USR"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FATTURA_PA_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("UTE", "NR_KEY", "PROGRESSIVO_INVIO")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "D3_USR"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_FATTURA_PA_FATTURA_PA_STATU" FOREIGN KEY ("STATUS_ID")
      REFERENCES "FE_ENGINE"."FATTURA_PA_STATUS" ("ID") ENABLE
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "D3_USR" ;

CREATE TABLE "FE_ENGINE"."FATTURA_PA_STATUS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COD_STATUS" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DESC_STATUS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_FATTURA_PA_STATUS" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "D3_USR"  ENABLE
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "D3_USR" ;
```

Any idea about it?

Comment: [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the tables involved. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I believe the reason could be in different execution plans that Oracle is using in the three queries; can you please post the plans?

Comment: Definitely the execution plan. `substr(nr_key,5,4)` does not always evaluate to a number. Different execution plans evaluate that expression for _every_ record or just for a subset of records. Short term you need to work out what data is the issue. Longer term you should not be storing numbers in varchar fields.

Comment: I didn't know waht an execution plan is... i'm trying to learn it now. Anyway I cannot make nr_key a number field, since it contains alphanumerical characters. But I am sure that there are numbers in that substr interval

Comment: `to_number(substr(nr_key,5,4))` just remove `to_number`. You will have implicit conversion to char from the other side in that case and it should be ok. Also you can add `numer = to_char(88)`. @Aleksej already said it's about execution plans. If you need to check substr is number or not, you need to use your own function for that purpose.

Comment: @Maik an execution plan is a representation of the path the optimizer has chosen to execute your SQL statement. The issue you're seeing is because your nr_key column doesn't always have numeric values in the 5th-8th positions across all rows, and Oracle may decide to try to apply the `to_number(substr(..))` *before* applying the filter that would ensure there would always be numerals in that section of the field for some versions of the query, but after in others.

Comment: One alternative would be to have a virtual column on your table that handles the cases where those characters are not numbers and outputs null instead and then select on that. Or, in 12.2, you can use the extended `to_number()` function to determine what to output in the event of a conversion error (I can't wait to get 12.2!!!)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the suggestions i got, after some tests, the only way I could get it work is this:

```
SELECT to_number(numero) FROM ( 
SELECT substr(nr_key,5,4) as numero
FROM fattura_pa 
 LEFT JOIN fattura_pa_status on status_id = id
WHERE ute = 'BX' and length(nr_key) < 21 
) 
where numero = lpad('88',4,'0')
```

Comment: There were quite a few useful suggestions in the comments, such as 'remove the `to_number` from the select list'. The problem with what you have now is that if the execution plan changes (the execution plan, among other things, decides what order the database does things in to make it run the fastest) then the error can appear again. You don't want to put code into a system that can break without warning at any time. The execution plan can change at any time depending for example on number of rows or  statistics.

Comment: To put it another way, right now the execution plan has decided to evaluate the `where` before the `select`, which means non numeric records never get to the select. However as you add rows to the table, the execution plan might change to one that evaluates the `select` before the `where`, and then it will apply `to_number` to every row, and your query will crash. So the short answer is: remove `to_number` from your select.

Comment: I've moved the to_number to the "external" select. I think that now the where in the subquery has to be done before the external select (which guarantees me numerical values). Or am I wrong?

Comment: You're probably wrong. Things are done in the order that the query processor decides is the quickest. You _can_ force it to run first by adding `AND ROWNUM > 0` to the inside query. That used to work. I don't know if it still does. It's a bit of a hack. You can also add the `MATERIALIZE` hint. Why do you need to cast the column to a number? Does something further upstream need it to be a number?

Comment: Just on your comment: _I cannot make nr_key a number field, since it contains alphanumerical characters_. If you are splitting the contents of this field into a number then it means that bit of data should be in a different field altogether. But I know that a redesign is not an option. Just observe and learn - never squash separate data into a single field

Comment: Yes I need it to be a number to show it in an interface. I could also ltrim the leading zeroes, but if the fields remains a string the interface ordering will be wrong (you know, 29 being bigger than 100...)

Comment: If you replace leading zeros with spaces it should order OK. Definitely an imperfect solution. Is this your interface or a vendor interface? If it's your interface I suggest formatting it in there, not in the query. I only keep banging on about it because this kind of query can just break at any time and you don't want that kind of thing in your system. Anyway good luck with that.